# Retrieving from HashMap of HashMap in Java 1.8

Tags: java, hashmap

For the following code, while printing out the HashMap of HashMap `temp`, why does it print

`{0={PRICE=2.2, NAME=2str}, 1={PRICE=2.2, NAME=2str}}`

as output instead of getting `{0={PRICE=2, NAME=1str}, 1={PRICE=2.2, NAME=2str}}`?

Please advise if there is a different fundamental concept that is used for creating such hashmaps?

I have tried inserting `temp.clear();` after the `test.put(0,temp);` but the result remains the same.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String, Object>> test = new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String, Object>>();
        HashMap<String,Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        temp.put("NAME","1str");
        temp.put("PRICE", 2);

        test.put(0,temp);
        System.out.println(temp);

        temp.put("NAME","2str");
        temp.put("PRICE",2.2);
        test.put(1,temp);

        System.out.println(temp);
        System.out.println(test);
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you're putting the same map into `test` twice. Don't reuse the map, create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same *instance* of the map, so think about what happens to the key.

Comment: @VasuMistry no, and clearly it didn't when you tried it. You are clearing the map you've already inserted.

Comment: Okay, this works in C++, so I thought it might work with Java too. Will read up on it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#clear-- but according to oracle doc, clear removes all the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new instance for temp, do not reuse the old one...
Something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String, Object>> test = new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String,Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    temp.put("NAME","1str");
    temp.put("PRICE", 2);

    test.put(0,temp);
    System.out.println(temp);

    temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    temp.put("NAME","2str");
    temp.put("PRICE",2.2);
    test.put(1,temp);

    System.out.println(temp);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use another instance of HashMap, this will do the trick

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> test = 
                          new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    temp.put("NAME", "1str");
    temp.put("PRICE", 2);

    test.put(0, temp);
    System.out.println(temp);

    HashMap<String, Object> temp1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    temp1.put("NAME", "2str");
    temp1.put("PRICE", 2.2);
    test.put(1, temp1);

    System.out.println(temp);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

---

You weren't getting the expected output because when you do

```
temp.put("NAME","2str");
```

you are replacing the previous value for the key `NAME`. The same thing happens when you do

```
temp.put("PRICE",2.2);
```

To avoid this you could create a new HashMap and prevent the *replacement of values for the same key*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a school question for you: Is java a pass by value (pass a copy of an object) or a pass by reference (pass the same object around) language?

Answer: Java is strictly pass by value, but it passes the value on the stack, which for objects happens to be the reference to the object in the heap.

What this means in the context of your question is that when you add the temp object into the test map, you're really adding the reference to the temp object.  This means that when you then modify the temp object further down, you are modifying the same object as you just added to the test map because the reference to the temp object is the same as the temp object you added into the map.  The reason why the values of index 0 and 1 are the same is because they are literally the same object.

Comment: This clarifies the doubt. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening, as you are putting in **test** with same **temp**. When you are putting in **temp**, it is changing its previous key-value pair as well as the value of key 0 of **test**.

You wrote you cleared the **temp** map. OK, clear removes all the key-value pair of a map, just like c++. But clearing **temp** also removed value of **0** key of **test**. Then when you put again into **temp**, it is changing its previous value(which is empty if you clear temp) of key 0 of **test**.

I just edited your code with some print. Hope it will help you if you run it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String, Object>> test = new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String,Object> temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    temp.put("NAME","1str");
    temp.put("PRICE", 2);
    test.put(0,temp);
    System.out.println("After first put:");
    System.out.println("temp is: " + temp);
    System.out.println("test is: " + test);

    temp.clear();
    System.out.println("After clearing it:");
    System.out.println("temp is: " + temp);
    System.out.println("test is: " + test);

    temp.put("NAME","2str");
    temp.put("PRICE",2.2);

    System.out.println("After second put in temp, you haven't put in test yet:");
    System.out.println("temp is: " + temp);
    System.out.println("test is: " + test);
    test.put(1,temp);

    System.out.println("After second put:");
    System.out.println("temp is: " + temp);
    System.out.println("test is: " + test);
}
```